# Cost of early color monitor versus TV

Tags: tv, monitor, history, crt

Back in the seventies and eighties, an important design choice for a desktop computer was whether to use a television or a dedicated monitor for display. A monitor could give better resolution; on the other hand, some people already had a television and could save money by reusing it.

Suppose the latter argument doesn't apply, and you assume customers will have to buy one or the other. Is there a big difference in manufacturing cost between a color monitor and a TV? Does the monitor save significantly by being free to implement an optimal design instead of complying with NTSC? Does the TV save significantly by being free to have poor resolution?

Comment: It made a world of difference.  Monitors had higher resolution, and were so much more expensive that monitors were in general smaller than TVs - a monitor the size of a typical TV would been far too expensive for home use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking an open-ended, [hypothetical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: @pipe Obviously it's no such thing; if you took the trouble to actually read the question, you would see it's asking about the historical fact of cost difference between two kinds of device that were actually manufactured in the time period in question.

Comment: Another thing is, it wasn't that some people had a TV.  It  is more like "most people" had a TV.  At least in the USA, and since you mention NTSC I assume you are talking about the US.

Comment: @JRE True, but not everyone wanted to locate their computer in the living room and contend for access to the family TV. Also there was the education market and in the case of early models of the Apple II, even the business market, contexts where there would not already be a TV per computer.

Comment: tv/monitor resolution was the same until VGA connectors. Most monitors in the 70-80s were  monochrome and cheaper. The color commodore 64 ones were slightly more expensive than a normal color TV, and had no tuner, but were very well-made; they found a long afterlife as video monitors for TV productions throughout the 90s.

Answer (score 2):

The cost is all in the vacuum tube. Until ~1990, color vacuum tubes which could display 1024x768 had been so expensive they still made monocrome ones and sold them along X terminals (which had been expensive devices themselves.)

A TV CRT could display roughly 400x300 pixels, and it stayed this way till today, because the NTSC/PAL TV standard does not have more pixels anyway.

Comment: Salesmen would pitch their green screens as a big advantage over black and white. Then the amber screens came in briefly.

Comment: The problem with bigger high-resolution vaccum cathode ray tubes is convergence. You simply cannot build them as flat as required for color TVs of the time and that's why they stayed a niche market for a long time.

Comment: Your math is off.  NTSC DVDs have 480 lines of resolution. My 27" sony from '98 displayed 800X600 from an s-video connection, and you could easily see each discrete pixel.

Comment: It's 480i. Interlace. And your Sony TV set is from 1998, not 1990.